# Nightwatch.js how to ignore main page? Or how to use window.location.host?

Tags: javascript, jquery, nightwatch.js, autotest, nightwatch

I'm a big noob in nightwatch.js but i have to decide this task. Please help me...

I have a simple autotest and the essence of the test is looking for links to the main page on **each page** of the site, and if there are less than 2 links then the test doesn't pass and gives an error.

```js
module.exports = {
  disabled: false,
  name: 'Homepage links',
  subtitle: ['There are less than 2 links to the main page.'],
  fn: function(browser) {
    browser.elements('css selector', 'a[href="/"]', function(result) {
      let allLinksToMain = result.value.length;

      if (allLinksToMain < 2) {
        browser.verify.ok(false, 'There are less than 2 links to the main page.');
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Do you know how to force autotest to **ignore the main page**?

Or maybe you know how to use **window.location.host** and **window.location.protocol** with nightwatch.js? I ask it, because i have some idea how to decide my task with clear JavaScript, but it doesn't work with nightwatch.js:

```js
let mainPageUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
let currentUrl = window.location.href;

let findLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href="/"]');

if (currentUrl === mainPageUrl) {
    console.log('This is the main page, do nothing!');
} else {
    console.log('Current URL: ' + currentUrl);
    if (findLinks.length >= 2) {
        console.log("The test passed without errors, links to the main page - " + findLinks.length);
    } else {
        console.log("The test didn't pass, links to the main page - " + findLinks.length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i've done it! I hope it'll help somebody :)

```js
module.exports = {
    disabled: false,
    name: 'Homepage links',
    subtitle: [
        'There are less than 2 links to the main page.',
        'There is less than 1 link in logo.',
    ],
    fn: function(browser) {
        browser.execute(
            function() {
                let mainPageUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
                let currentUrl = window.location.href;
                return result = {
                    main: mainPageUrl,
                    current: currentUrl,
                }
            }, [],
            function(result) {
                if (result.value.current !== result.value.main) {

                    browser.elements('css selector', 'a[href="/"]', function(result) {
                        if (result.value.length < 2) {
                            browser.verify.ok(false, 'There are less than 2 links to the main page.');
                        } else {
                            browser.elements('css selector', 'a[href="/"] > img, a[href="/"] > svg', function(result) {
                                if (result.value.length < 1) {
                                    browser.verify.ok(false, 'There is less than 1 link in logo.');
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        );
    }
};
```